# Subscript Out of range error message in every method/property of Workbook VBA

Tags: vba

I am getting an "Subscript Out of range" error message in every property/Method of Workbook. Below is the code.

```
Sub comparator()

Dim CFileName, DFileName, FileName1, FileName2 As String
Dim sh As Worksheet, wb As Workbook

CFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(Filefilter:="excel Files,*.xlsx", Title:="Select the File to be processed")
FileName1 = Mid(CFileName, InStrRev(CFileName, Application.PathSeparator) + 1, 99)

DFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(Filefilter:="excel Files,*.xlsx", Title:="Select the File to be processed")
FileName2 = Mid(CFileName, InStrRev(CFileName, Application.PathSeparator) + 1, 99)

Workbooks("FileName1").Worksheets.Copy After:=Workbooks("FileName2").Worksheets(1)

End sub
```

Below code line also gives the same error. So it looks like some issue with "FileName" which is a subscript. I spend almost a 12 to find out the issue but fed up now.

```
Msgbox Workbooks("FileName1").Worksheets.Count
```

---

Sorry for all these small mistakes, this is code I types here in browser. Below is the code from my Excel VBA editor.

```
Sub comparator()

Dim PreFileName As String Dim CFileName As String Dim DFileName As String Dim FileName1 As String Dim FileName2 As String Dim XLApp, XLDoc, DestObject As Object

Set XLApp = CreateObject("excel.Application")

CFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(Filefilter:="excel Files,*.xlsx", Title:="Select the File to be processed") Set XLDoc = XLApp.Workbooks.Open(CFileName) FileName1 = Mid(CFileName, InStrRev(CFileName, Application.PathSeparator) + 1, 99) XLApp.Visible = True

DFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(Filefilter:="excel Files,*.xlsx", Title:="Select the File to be processed") Set XLDoc = XLApp.Workbooks.Open(DFileName) FileName2 = Mid(DFileName, InStrRev(CFileName, Application.PathSeparator) + 1, 99) XLApp.Visible = True

Workbooks("FileName1").Worksheets.Copy After:=Workbooks("FileName2").Worksheets(1)

End Sub
```

Comment: You realize that `CFileName`, `DFileName`, and `FileName1` are `Variant` variables right? Only `FileName2` is declared as a `String` - not related to your error though, but just thought I'd point it out.

Comment: I have made the changes and declared all the variables u mentioned above as String. But as this was not related my issue and hence error remains.

Comment: remove the quotes, you probably do not have a workbook with the name FileName1.  I am guessing you are trying to use the variable FileName1 so when you put quotes around it, it now just becomes a string with the value of FileName1.  Do the same for FileName2

Comment: Sorry for all these small mistakes, this is code I types here in browser. Below is the code from my Excel VBA editor.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> InStrRev(CFileName, Application.PathSeparator) + 1, 99)
> ```

The 99 is a problem here. This is going to fail with a *subscript out of range* error whenever `CFileName` is shorter than 99 characters.

Why not just drop that optional parameter?

```
InStrRev(CFileName, Application.PathSeparator) + 1)
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" is pretty vague. Have you tried setting a breakpoint and stepping through your code? There are several places your code can blow up with the error you've specified.

Comment: I have made all the research and couldn't find out the issue. Issue is only at WorkBooks("Subscript"). I have tried a one liner code with Msgbox Workbooks("FileName1").Worksheets.Count and this also gives the same error message. Thanks to everyone for the quick replies. But issue is still unresolved.

Comment: @Sorceri's answer *does* address the `MsgBox Workbooks("FileName1")` issue - unless the workbook is *actually called* "FileName1", that's going to blow up. Also your code isn't opening the workbooks you're prompting filenames for... assign a `Workbook` object variable, something like `Set myworkbook = Workbooks.Open(FileName1)`, and then just access that object's worksheets collection.

Comment: @akashbondre  You need to provide some more detail other then, the issue is still unresolved or It doesnt work.  Are you getting more errors, same error, what is not working?!?!?!  Help us help you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25812025/suscript-out-of-range-error-only-after-dynamic-opening-of-input-sheets-vba

Answer (score 1):

Per the notes in my comment, you have to remove the quotes to use the variable

```
Sub comparator()
On Error GoTo errHandler
Dim CFileName, DFileName, FileName1, FileName2 As String
Dim sh As Worksheet, wb As Workbook

CFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(Filefilter:="excel Files,*.xlsx", Title:="Select the File to be processed")
FileName1 = Mid(CFileName, InStrRev(CFileName, Application.PathSeparator) + 1, 99)

DFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(Filefilter:="excel Files,*.xlsx", Title:="Select the File to be processed")
FileName2 = Mid(CFileName, InStrRev(CFileName, Application.PathSeparator) + 1, 99)

Workbooks(FileName1).Worksheets.Copy After:=Workbooks(FileName2).Worksheets(1)

errHandler:
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox Err.Description
End If

End Sub
```