# Suscript Out of Range error only after Dynamic opening of input sheets, VBA

Tags: vba

Below code works without error if I keep the two input excel files "CFileName" and "DFileName" open manually. But when I try to open these two files dynamically by uncommenting the code lines in below code then it gives me an error "Subscript Out of Range". I even tried inserting the Delays but didn't work.

```
Sub Comparator()

Dim PreFileName As String

Dim CFileName As String

Dim DFileName As String

Dim FileName1 As String

Dim FileName2 As String

Dim XLApp, XLDoc, DestObject As Object

Dim sh As Worksheet, wb As Workbook

Set XLApp = CreateObject("excel.Application")

CFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(Filefilter:="excel Files,*.xlsx", Title:="Select the File to be processed")

' Set XLDoc = XLApp.Workbooks.Open(CFileName)

FileName1 = Mid(CFileName, InStrRev(CFileName, Application.PathSeparator) + 1)

XLApp.Visible = True

DFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(Filefilter:="excel Files,*.xlsx", Title:="Select the File to be processed")

' Set XLDoc = XLApp.Workbooks.Open(DFileName)

FileName2 = Mid(DFileName, InStrRev(CFileName, Application.PathSeparator) + 1)

XLApp.Visible = True

Windows(FileName1).Activate

Workbooks(FileName1).Worksheets("Copy").Copy After:=Workbooks(FileName2).Worksheets(3)

End Sub
```

Comment: This line: `Dim XLApp, XLDoc, DestObject As Object` doesn't do what you think it does. Try the following instead. `Dim XLApp As Object, XLDoc As Object, DestObject As Object`

Answer (score 1):

Tested and Working.

```
Sub Comparator()

Dim PreFileName As String

Dim CFileName As String

Dim DFileName As String

Dim FileName1 As String

Dim FileName2 As String

Dim XLApp, XLDoc, DestObject As Object

Dim sh As Worksheet, wb As Workbook

Set XLApp = CreateObject("excel.Application")

CFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(Filefilter:="excel Files,*.xlsx", Title:="Select the File to be processed")

 Set XLDoc = XLApp.Workbooks.Open(CFileName)

FileName1 = Mid(CFileName, InStrRev(CFileName, Application.PathSeparator) + 1)

XLApp.Visible = True

DFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(Filefilter:="excel Files,*.xlsx", Title:="Select the File to be processed")

 Set DestObject = XLApp.Workbooks.Open(DFileName)

FileName2 = Mid(DFileName, InStrRev(CFileName, Application.PathSeparator) + 1)


XLDoc.Activate

XLDoc.Worksheets("Copy").Copy After:=DestObject.Worksheets(3)

End Sub
```

Comment: You mean you tested my code and its working with dynamic selection of files without error??

Comment: Your modifications are working...I am checking your code for the changes you made..Thanks..But I have more doubts..I will comment here soon..Thanks once again..

Comment: Now I am trying to Make this code running sheet as the destination Sheet, any pointers on this?

Comment: remove the reference to DestObject leaving just After:Worksheets(3) which then makes the reference of Worksheets(3) point to the current workbook.

Comment: You mean XLDoc1.Worksheets("Copy").Copy After:=Worksheets(3)

Comment: Its giving run time error 1004 Application defined or Object defined error.

Comment: Sorceri, Yes there are 3 worksheets...Looks like Copy method is asking for a object reference to destination sheet, which we have removed as we needed current sheet as destination sheet. Is there any way we can create object reference for the current sheet(sheet from where code is running).Thanks.

Comment: assuming that the sheet is the active sheet at the time the code is run you can create a variable Dim ws as worksheet then at the beginning of the code set the reference to the active sheet.  set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet  then reference ws in the After:= line of the Copy method.